# Macbook Air reboots on closing Android emulator

Tags: macos, android-studio, android-emulator

Macbook Air crashes whenever I close my Android emulator and reboots with error message. I have latest version of HAXM (7.3.2).

Answer (score 0):

I don't find any proper answer on this topic but as my personal experience this happens due to extra load on memory while working on big Android projects and can be checked in memory monitor while building your app. So, now I am using real device instead of emulator and it's working fine.